# Previously selected UICollectionViewCells are deselected after non-selectable cell is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am implementing a UICollectionView with multiple selection enabled.

Some of my cells are selectable, some are not. Here is the chain of events:

1. I select a few cells by tapping on them and returning `YES` to

   - `shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath:`
   - `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:`
2. I try to select a non-selectable cell by tapping on it (the non-selectionable aspect is achieved by returning `NO` to `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:`)
3. Result: All selected cells are deselected and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` is called on them. NOTE: `shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` is not called.

Expected Result: Nothing happens.

Is this normal behavior? I can't find anything in the docs. If so, how can I go about not deselecting my cells?

Comment: Have you set the table view's `allowsMultipleSelection` to YES?

Comment: I knew I was going to get this question... Should have mentioned it... Yes I did.

Comment: Try implementing the delegate method `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`, set a breakpoint in it, and see when is it called. That might help understand what's happening.

Comment: I am working with UICollectionView, not UITableView. But since these 2 are very similar, I looked into it. There is no `willDoXOrY` methods in the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol but there is a `shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath` one. I checked, it's not called. Good idea though.

Comment: @BlackRider actually, I did mention on the first line of my post "with multiple selection enabled".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath=NO does not avoid deselecting old selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477614/uicollectionview-shouldselectitematindexpath-no-does-not-avoid-deselecting-old-s)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35348930/171089

Answer (score 7):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeue...

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = isSelectableIndexPath(indexPath)

    return cell
}

func isSelectableIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    //logic to check if cell is selectable
}
```

This works by disabling interaction with the cell.

Comment: Thanks ... this worked for me and is less hacky than the other reply which was also good, but not very easy for others to understand why you're doing what you are

Comment: Perfect solution, tnx a lot .

Answer (score 6):

I had to face exactly the same problem, with `collectionView:shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` not being called. My solution consist of manually reselect the currently selected cell if I'm tapping on a non-selectable one:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL isSelectable = /* decide if currently tapped cell should be selectable */;

    NSIndexPath *selectedItemIndexPath = /* NSIndexPath of the current selected cell in the collection view, set in collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: */;

    if (!isSelectable) {
        // the cell isn't selectable, we have to reselect the previously selected cell that has lost selection in the meanwhile
        // without reloading first the cell the selection is not working...
        [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedItemIndexPath]];
        [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:selectedItemIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

    return isSelectable;
}
```

If your collection view is scrolling (hiding the currently selected cell) remember to reselect the cell in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

I don't like too much this solution, it's too "hacky", but it works. I would expect to do all the logic in the `collectionView:shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` but it isn't called and I don't understand why.